# how to send email with sendmail nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sendmail, nodemailer

I am currently struggling with sending email through sendmail package in nodejs.
I just have simple form on my portfolio with name email and message fields.
How do i send the email to me from email provided in this form field?

This is what i have so far and it doesn't work at all.

index.html

```
    <form onsubmit="sendEmail()">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="_name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="_message" name="message" cols="30" rows="10"
            placeholder="Enter your message"
        ></textarea>
        <input id="_submit" type="submit" value="Send a Message">
    </form>
```

email.js

```
 app.use( cors())
app.use( express.json() )

app.post("/sendMail", (req, res) =>{

    const _mail = req.body.email 
    const _name = req.body.name
    const _message = req.body.message
    try {
        sendmail({
            from: 'fake@gmail.com',
            to: 'fake2@gmail.com',
            subject: 'test sendmail',
            html: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
          }, function(err, reply) {
              console.log(err && err.stack);
              console.dir(reply);
            });
            res.send({message: "mail send"})
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    console.log("mail sended")

})


app.listen( 5000, () => console.log("back-end is running on port: 5000"))
```

and index.js font-end fetch

```
 _submit.onclick =  async event =>  {
        event.preventDefault()
        const _name = $.find("#_name").value
        const _email = $.find("#_email").value
        const _message = $.find("#_message").value
        const _error = $.find("#_error")

        if ( _name.length < 3 ) {
            _error.innerText = "Name must be at least 3 characters long"
            return
        }
        if ( _email.length < 5 || _email.includes("@") === false  || _email.includes(".") === false ) {
            _error.innerText = "Not valid email adress"
            return
        }
        // CLEAR ERROR OUTPUT
        _error.innerText = ""

        // DATA TO BE SEND TO SERVER
        const data = { 
            name: _name,
            email: _email,
            message: _message
        }


        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/sendMail', {
            method : "POST",
            headers:  {
                
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify( data )
        })

        let res_data = await response.json()
        console.log(res_data)

        
        console.log(_name.length, _email, _message)
    }
```

So I am getting JSON in console

```
{message: "email sent"}
```

and also `"email send"` in server console.

All seems to be working fine so I don't know  whats actually wrong.
I dont recieve any emails...

I also tried nodemailer but it requires auth but on my website its just simple contact form without auths.

Hope you guys could help me out :)

Comment: What if you move `res.send({message: "mail sent"})` into the `sendmail` callback

Comment: did you check your spam folder? or enable less secure apps on google

Comment: ye i checked spam foler and nothing in there :(

Comment: @Phix I added it to callback function of `sendmail` but i dont get `res.send `in console anymore

Comment: @Shubh I also had enabled `Less secure app access` on email i want to send mail to

Comment: No errors and you're sending to an actual email address correct?

Comment: That's correct i edited emails just to hide real ones :)  No errors in server console or client console that's why I don't know what's going on. I tried to add `try catch` block around `sendmail` but also no errors.